# position of my form's controls aren't in right place with same resolution in another computer

Tags: c#, winforms

I set my control's position on form in resolution like 1280*1024 but when move my program to another computer with same resolution, control's position aren't in right place

why?

Comment: What kind of application is this? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: The reason is that the fonts are different on the two machines. If the exact font specified is not on the target machine, Windows picks something "close". As Micah describes, you need to use docking, anchoring, and/or layout containers to create a Form that is flexible.

Comment: no,i check the font and install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Docking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w8z0xh4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [Anchoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of just placing them on the form. This will also help when you re size your form and maximize and restore the form.

Comment: but my program is correct on my computer with this resolution

Comment: Exactly the reason why I would use Docking and Anchoring